"which pip" and "pip --version" give different locations
How's the following possible:
max@p17:~$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip

max@p17:~$ pip --version
pip 24.0 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

so where's my pip installed?

Try cat /usr/bin/pip. Its likely a shell script that imports and runs pip's main().

gives me this cat: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory

which isn't a shell builtin. It only knows about the PATH; it doesn't know anything about shell functions or aliases or cached lookups. Don't ever use it when you need your answer to be precise -- in bash, use type pip, or in baseline POSIX shells, command -v pip

That said, tdelaney is on-point. The executable pip is a wrapper that invokes the module pip, so pip --version tells you where the module lives, not where the executable lives.

I closed this as a duplicate of "Explain Python entry points?" because that's what you're seeing here: the result from which is an executable (created by setuptools on account of an entrypoint configured to request it) that starts a Python interpreter and tells it to run code from a given module. (Note that scripts are executables -- in this context an "executable" is just something execve() can run -- though in some cases pip creates compiled binaries; on Windows, f/e, its entrypoints are .exe files, though they do the same thing of starting a separate Python interpreter).

All that said, it's not likely that cat /usr/bin/pip gave No such file or directory in the same context as which pip returned /usr/bin/pip -- make sure you weren't in a Docker container for one but not the other, or on a different host, or in a chroot, or so forth.

(BTW, you don't need the executable pip at all, and it's arguably better practice not to use it: python -m pip is more direct, taking the first Python interpreter in your PATH and telling that interpreter to load the pip module).

There we are -- the edit affirms the answer (or, rather, the selection of an appropriate duplicate). Your /usr/bin/pip is generated code that invokes the entrypoint pip._internal.cli.main:main. That module is found via a sys.path lookup as usual.

I agree with @CharlesDuffy on that. You want to make sure you get the same pip as your python.

You can see the entrypoint (called a "script" in pyproject.toml there; "entrypoint" was the old setuptools name) configured in pip's source code at https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/d94806f9592f03cc092079f4517039ea6c1b2e0e/pyproject.toml#L32-L34

(btw, to add some nuance to a prior statement -- which isn't a builtin on POSIX-standard shells; so on dash or bash or ksh or so forth, it's a separate executable and doesn't have access to shell internals or configuration. zsh goes its own way -- it doesn't try to be POSIX-compliant -- and there, which does have access to internals).

@CharlesDuffy _that invokes the entrypoint pip.internal.cli.main:main. That module is found via a sys.path lookup as usual. - so what I get through which pip is a script executable that from pip._internal..., and pip module is resolved in one of directories listed through /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)", correct?

@CharlesDuffy, so in the list returned by /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)" I found the following directory /home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip, which also contains the __init__.py file which marks it as a package module, so I guess that's why I see this path when I do pip --version. The same path is outputted when I do python -m pip --version

Related, not a duplicate: different pips are used between pip --version and which pip

/usr/bin/pip is an entrypoint created from this definition in the form of an executable script file that imports pip through a module resolution path:
~$ cat /usr/bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r"(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$", "", sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())

The list of python module resolution paths:
/usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

contains these directories:
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

The first one is user-site that is picked first:
$ /usr/bin/python -m site --user-site
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

and that's the directory that is printed by pip --version. That's the same directory resolved by calling python -m pip.

You could also look at import pip; print(pip), which should show <module 'pip' from '/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'>. Or more directly, pip.__file__.

To make sys.path more readable, you could do /usr/bin/python3 -c "import sys; print(*map(repr, sys.path), sep='\n')"
